# Run first migration SQLite with Adinis 5 - Cannot find module '@vscode/sqlite3'

Tags: sqlite, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace, lucid

When i run this command "node ace migration:run" the terminal show me this error:

Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Cannot find module '@vscode/sqlite3'
...
...
...

I am using Adonis JS 5 but the SQLite database is not working. Any idea what it could be?

I tried just running the initial migration command where I expected the database file to be created automatically (just like version 4 did)

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed the latest version of Lucid without taking note of the changelogs and breaking changes.

You need to use `@vscode/sqlite3` instead of `sqlite3`.